# unable to set adapter in android getting error in settext

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, custom-adapter

I have made a custom adapter for seting to a listView in android,I am paring some jsondata and want to set in into a list view,I have tried as belo but its not workig,My code as below,pls help me .

**myactivity.java**

```
package com.epe.yehki.ui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.epe.yehki.adapter.CategoryAdapter;
import com.epe.yehki.adapter.ProductAdapter;
import com.epe.yehki.backend.ServiceHandler;
import com.epe.yehki.uc.Header;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Const;
import com.example.yehki.R;

public class ProSubCategoryActivity extends Activity {

    int flag;
    public Header header;
    public TextView title;
    Bitmap bitmap;;
    private ProductAdapter productContent;
    private CategoryAdapter categoryContent;
    // PRODUCTS....
    // arrayLists......
    public static ArrayList<String> productArray;
    public static ArrayList<String> categoryArray;

    //

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray subcategories = null;
    JSONArray products = null;
    public String catid;
    public String id;
    String name;
    ListView lv;

    JSONObject jsonObj;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> subcategoryList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Intent in = null;
    // new
    public String proname;
    public String prodesc;
    public String proimg;

    public String proMinOrderQty;
    public String proMinPrice;
    public String proMaxPrice;
    public String proTerms;
    public String proId;

    // new
    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/categories.php";

    private static String mainurl = "http://yehki.epagestore.in/";
    public String suburl = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);
        this.header = (Header) findViewById(R.id.headersubcat);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        // getting intent data
        categoryArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        productArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        in = getIntent();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        categoryContent = new CategoryAdapter(this, categoryArray);
        // Get JSON values from previous intent

        try {
            catid = in.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_CAT_ID);
            name = in.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_CAT_NAME);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("::::::::::::::MY CATEGORY ID::::::::::::::IN SUB "
                + catid);
        subcategoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        productList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        suburl = "http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/categories.php?"
                + Const.TAG_CAT_ID + "=" + catid;
        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::MY SUBCATEGORY URL::::::::::::"
                + suburl);
        title.setText(name);

        // Displaying all values on the screen

        new GetSubCategories().execute();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                if (flag == 0) {
                    String catname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                            .getText().toString();

                    in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SubCategoryTwoActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(Const.TAG_CAT_NAME, catname);
                    in.putExtra(Const.TAG_CAT_ID, catid);

                    startActivity(in);
                } else {
                    in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ProductDetailActivity.class);
                    proname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_label))
                            .getText().toString();
                    proId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pro_id))
                            .getText().toString();
                    System.out
                            .println(":::::::::::::::;;THE INTENT FOR THE PRODUCUT DETIALS ACTIVITY================="
                                    + proname
                                    + "  proDuct Id::::::::::::>>>>>>>>>"
                                    + proId);

                    in.putExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID, proId);
                    in.putExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, proname);
                    in.putExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_IMG, proimg);
                    in.putExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_ORDER_QTY, proMinOrderQty);
                    in.putExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_PRICE, proMinPrice);
                    in.putExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MAX_PRICE, proMaxPrice);
                    in.putExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, prodesc);
                    in.putExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_PAYMENT_TERMS, proTerms);

                    /*
                     * in.putExtra(TAG_CAT_NAME, p); in.putExtra(TAG_CAT_ID,
                     * catid);
                     */

                    startActivity(in);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private class GetSubCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProSubCategoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::SUB URL:::::::::::::::::"
                    + suburl);
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(suburl, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {

                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_CAT_LlIS)) {

                        System.out
                                .println("::::::::::::::::true::::::::::::::::"
                                        + jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_CAT_LlIS));
                        subcategories = jsonObj
                                .getJSONArray(Const.TAG_CAT_LlIS);
                        if (subcategories != null
                                && subcategories.length() != 0) {
                            // looping through All Contacts
                            flag = 0;
                            System.out
                                    .println(":::::::::::FLAG IN SUB:::::::::::"
                                            + subcategories.length());
                            for (int i = 0; i < subcategories.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = subcategories.getJSONObject(i);

                                id = c.getString(Const.TAG_CAT_ID);
                                String name = c.getString(Const.TAG_CAT_NAME);

                                // tmp hashmap for single category
                                /*
                                 * HashMap<String, String> subcategory = new
                                 * HashMap<String, String>();
                                 * 
                                 * // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                                 * // value subcategory.put(Const.TAG_CAT_ID,
                                 * id); subcategory.put(Const.TAG_CAT_NAME,
                                 * name);
                                 * 
                                 * // adding contact to contact list
                                 * subcategoryList.add(subcategory);
                                 */

                                // new adde 3=04=2014
                                // categoryArray.add(id);
                                categoryArray.add(name);
                                System.out
                                        .println("::::::::::My category:::::::"
                                                + categoryArray.get(i)
                                                        .toString().trim());
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_LlST)) {
                        flag = 1;
                        System.out
                                .println("::::::::::::::::true::::::::::::::::"
                                        + jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_LlST));
                        products = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_LlST);
                        if (products != null && products.length() != 0) {
                            // looping through All Contacts

                            System.out
                                    .println(":::::::::::FLAG IN SUB:::::::::::"
                                            + flag);
                            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                                id = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
                                String proname = c
                                        .getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                                String prodesc = c
                                        .getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION);
                                String proimg = Const.API_HOST + "/"
                                        + c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_IMG);
                                System.out
                                        .println(":::::::::::::::My Image Url:::::::::::::"
                                                + proimg);
                                String proMinOrderQty = c
                                        .getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_ORDER_QTY);
                                String proMinPrice = c
                                        .getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_PRICE);
                                String proMaxPrice = c
                                        .getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MAX_PRICE);

                                String proTerms = c
                                        .getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_PAYMENT_TERMS);
                                System.out
                                        .println(":::::::::::::My prododuct name+++++++:::::::::::::"
                                                + proname);
                                System.out
                                        .println(":::::::::::::My prododuct image+++++++:::::::::::::"
                                                + proimg);
                                System.out
                                        .println(":::::::::::::My prododuct min order qty+++++++:::::::::::::"
                                                + proMinOrderQty);

                                // tmp hashmap for single category
                                HashMap<String, String> product = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                                // value
                                product.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID, id);
                                product.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, proname);
                                product.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_IMG, proimg);
                                product.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_ORDER_QTY,
                                        proMinOrderQty);
                                product.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                        prodesc);

                                // adding contact to contact list
                                productList.add(product);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler",
                            "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out
                        .println("::::::::::::::::::got an error::::::::::::");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * 
             * */

            if (flag == 0) {

                lv.setAdapter(categoryContent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ProSubCategoryActivity.this, "Please wait", 1)
                        .show();
                /*
                 * ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                 * ProSubCategoryActivity.this, productList,
                 * R.layout.activity_single_produt, new String[] {
                 * Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID, Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME,
                 * Const.TAG_PRODUCT_IMG, Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_ORDER_QTY,
                 * Const.TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION }, new int[] {
                 * R.id.product_label, R.id.iv_product_img, R.id.min_qty,
                 * R.id.pro_desc, R.id.pro_id }); setListAdapter(adapter);
                 */
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
package com.epe.yehki.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.yehki.R;

public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> categoryArray;
    private Context mContext;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context paramContext,
            ArrayList<String> paramArrayList) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.categoryArray = paramArrayList;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.categoryArray.size();
    }

    public void setAllItems(ArrayList<String> paramArrayList) {
        this.categoryArray.addAll(paramArrayList);
    }

    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        Viewholder localViewholder = null;
        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,
                    paramViewGroup, false);
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();

            localViewholder.categoryName = ((TextView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.name));

            paramView.setTag(localViewholder);

        } else {
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();
            localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
        }

        localViewholder.categoryName.setText(categoryArray.get(paramInt)
                .indexOf(0));

        return paramView;

    }

    static class Viewholder {

        private TextView categoryName;

    }
}
```

Comment: remove this `localViewholder = new Viewholder();` in else

Comment: post you logcat what's error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code , try this now

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> categoryArray;
    private Context mContext;
    private  Viewholder localViewholder = null;

public CategoryAdapter(Context paramContext,
        ArrayList<String> paramArrayList) {
    this.mContext = paramContext;
    this.categoryArray = paramArrayList;

}

public int getCount() {
    return this.categoryArray.size();
}

public void setAllItems(ArrayList<String> paramArrayList) {
    this.categoryArray.addAll(paramArrayList);
}

public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
    return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
}

public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
    return paramInt;
}

public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
            .getSystemService("layout_inflater");

    if (paramView == null) {
         localViewholder = new Viewholder();
        paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,
                paramViewGroup, false);
        localViewholder = new Viewholder();

        localViewholder.categoryName = ((TextView) paramView
                .findViewById(R.id.name));

        paramView.setTag(localViewholder);

    } else {

        localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
    }

    localViewholder.categoryName.setText(categoryArray.get(paramInt)
            .indexOf(0));

    return paramView;

}

static class Viewholder {

    private TextView categoryName;

}
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me for one more problem i have just posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830031/lazy-list-not-working-properly-in-android

Comment: @user3484753 : Check your problem , i have provided one link of JSON parsing demo , please go through it.